# How can I change culture when the use click on a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I've created two resources files inside a folder. And I'm using each on of them as language resource for my website.
inside the Global.asax I've used the following code to change the language:

```
        protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string culture = "en";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture);
    }
```

The issue is that, every time I want to change the language I have to access the code above and change the culture value.

Is there anyway to accomplish that with Button click event ?

Answer (score 0):

For using buttons to switch languages, you could try to refer to the following methods and codes.

The project structure is as follows:

[image]

Page1.aspx.resx:

[image]

Page1.aspx.ku.resx:

[image]

Page2.aspx.resx:

[image]

Page2.aspx.ku.resx:

[image]

The code of **Page1.aspx**:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Page1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Language.Page1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <div>
             <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"  Text="English" Width="80px"></asp:Label>
             <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="en-us" OnClick="Button2_Click"  />
         </div>
         <p>
             <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"  Text="Kurdish" Width="80px"></asp:Label>
             <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="ku" OnClick="Button3_Click"  />
         </p>
         <p>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" meta:resourceKey="Button1" runat="server" Text=" Hello" />
         </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code of **Page1.aspx.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
namespace Language
{
  public partial class Page1 : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
      if (Session["lang"] != null)
      {
        Culture = Session["lang"].ToString();
        UICulture = Session["lang"].ToString();
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Session["lang"].ToString());
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Session["lang"].ToString());
        base.InitializeCulture();
      }
    }
    protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Session["lang"] = Button2.Text;
      Response.Redirect("Page1.aspx");
    }
    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Session["lang"] = Button3.Text;
      Response.Redirect("Page1.aspx");
    }
  }
}
```

The code of **Page2.aspx**:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Page2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Language.Page2" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="Label1" Text="ok"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The code of **Page2.aspx.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading;
namespace Language
{
  public partial class Page2 : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
      if (Session["lang"] != null)
      {
        Culture = Session["lang"].ToString();
        UICulture = Session["lang"].ToString();
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Session["lang"].ToString());
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(Session["lang"].ToString());
        base.InitializeCulture();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, @M Awad. Does this solution solve your problem? If it is solved, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.